# How to read all files line by line from a directory using perl?

Tags: perl

For example I have a folder called verilog inside that folder I have some more folders and files.

I want to search for a pattern in each file line by line, keeping count of how many times the pattern has been matched, then print the filename, line number and count.

Comment: file name, line number and count ...so you want the count per line? 
It doesn't make much sense to print line numbers and count per file.

Comment: why don't use just use awk (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) for this task?

Comment: No I wanted to do like this and I wanted to do in perl

Answer (score 1):

File name and line numbers:

```
system("find verilog -type f -exec grep -Hn pattern {} +")
```

File name and count per file:

```
system("find verilog -type f -exec grep -Hc pattern {} +")
```

Comment: #!usr/bin/perl -w

my @FILES;

#my $string="clk";

opendir(DIR,"/home/prodigydell3/verilog") || die "cannot open dir:$!";

@FILES = readdir DIR;
closedir(DIR);

foreach my $file (@FILES){

open (FH,"/home/prodigydell3/verilog/") or die "$!";
while(<FH>){
my $string = "clk";
if ($string =/clk/i){

print "FH has the pattern clk in $. \n";

}
}
}

Comment: I already have the perl script like this, In this I need to print the line number , file name in each file in the directory and the count of the pattern which I am searching. Right now i am able to print only in the folder verilog but there are also other two foldres in verilog which not geting printed. Please help me on this.

Comment: I could not get you what you are saying!

Answer (score 1):

The below commands to be given from inside the "verilog" directory:
Using grep -R:

For filename and line numbers:

```
grep -RHn pattern * | cut -d: -f-2
```

For filename and count:

```
grep -RHc india * | awk -F":" '$2!=0'
```

Comment: #!usr/bin/perl -w

my @FILES;

#my $string="clk";

opendir(DIR,"/home/prodigydell3/verilog") || die "cannot open dir:$!";

@FILES = readdir DIR;
closedir(DIR);

foreach my $file (@FILES){

open (FH,"/home/prodigydell3/verilog/") or die "$!";
while(<FH>){
my $string = "clk";
if ($string =/clk/i){

print "FH has the pattern clk in $. \n";

}
}
}

Answer (score 1):

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use File::Find;
use File::Slurp;

my $In_dir='some_path';
my @all_files;
my $pattern='test>testing string(\n|\t|\s)</test'

File::Find:find(
sub{
  push @all_files,$File::Find:name if(-f $File::Find:name);
},$In_dir);

foreach my $file_(@all_files){
  my @file_con=read_file($file_);
  my $lne_cnt;
  foreach my $con(@file_con){
   my $match_="true" if($con=~m/$pattern/igs);
   $lne_cnt++;
  }
 my $tot_line_in_file=$lne_cnt;
}
```

Comment: Can't locate FILE/Find.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.12.4 /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.12 /usr/share/perl/5.12 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at sample2.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at sample2.pl line 3.

Comment: Previously I got the output that mac_top.v has clk in line 45.but now nothing!!!!!!!